# Digitising - Separate fill and line opacities (or remove fill)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, development, digitizing, interface

I have a client who specialises in aerial photograph interpretation and is in the process of moving from AutoCAD to QGIS. They find the auto 'fill' when digitising polygons really disruptive and although we can tweak the opacity (see ["add feature" tool QGIS 2.0 - polygon fill blocks view of what I want to digitize](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79783/add-feature-tool-qgis-2-0-polygon-fill-blocks-view-of-what-i-want-to-digitiz)) ideally we would want a solid line with no fill while digitising.

So far as I am aware there isn't a plugin or other existing solution for this, so my question is how complicated would it be to change the settings to separate opacity of line and fill when digitising? Could this be done via a plugin or only through extending the core QGIS functions?

Comment: Please note that contractor solicitations/recommendations are off-topic here, and such posts may be removed. You might consider posting a feature request to QGIS developers (since I don't think it could qualify as a 'bug'): http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/General_User_Interface_Wishes

Comment: Thanks for your response and (for the heads up re paid developers). My question was really to understand if this feature could be refined / tailored to this purpose with a plugin or requires a feature request. I'm guessing from your answer that a feature request is required...

Comment: I don't know enough about programming or QGIS' code to say if it could be done with a plugin or would require core modification. I only suggested a feature request since that seemed like the 'path of least resistance' (ie a theoretical small change to existing code rather than coding a whole new plugin).

Comment: A possible workaround is to digitize as lines and later on covert these to polygons