# Fill of sketch polygon blocks view of what I'm trying to digitize

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am trying to digitize polygons using QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa, but the red fill of the sketch polygon blocks me from seeing the imagery that I need in order to draw said polygon.

I have tried going into Settings > Options > Digitizing and changing the opaqity of the rubberband to a lower number (as described here: ["add feature" tool QGIS 2.0 - polygon fill blocks view of what I want to digitize](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79783/add-feature-tool-qgis-2-0-polygon-fill-blocks-view-of-what-i-want-to-digitiz)), but this does nothing. I believe it's a bug, but wanted to check to see if anyone else had figured this out.

Comment: Try to put a opacity value from 30% to 50% in the rubberband color. That worked for me. As mentioned in the quoted question you can alter this at Settings/options/digitizing/rubberband- Pick the color of your likings and assign a opacity of 30-50%.